# Multiple buttons per item instead of just one button per item in my Shopping List App?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

Im making a shopping list app. I can add items into a list and once they appear, I've made it so that a button appears next to each item. That button is there so that you can click on it and remove your item from the list when you're ready.

The problem here is, that after you add a few items, the button increases itself. Basically, instead of there being just one button for one item, there are multiple buttons per item as the list increases. I only want one button per item. Can you please take a look at my code and help? Thanks a lot!

```js
$(document).ready(function() {

  $('#removebox').hide();

  //When you click send it sends the item to the list
  $('#send').click(function() {
    var userMessage = $('.text-box').val();
    $('.text-box').val('');

    //If theres nothing in the text-box and send is clicked an alert pops up
    if (!userMessage) {
      alert("Please add some items to the list!")
    } else {
      //This appends the item typed into the text-box to the list
      $('.container').append('<li>' + userMessage + '</li>');
      addBox();
    }
  });


  //This adds the remove button next to each item in the list      
  function addBox() {
    $('.container li').append($('#removebox'));
    $('#removebox').show();

  };
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="title" width="100%">
  <p> Shopping List</p>
</div>

<div class="container">
  <input class="text-box" placeholder="Please enter an item">
  <button id="send">submit</button>
  <button id="removebox">X</button>
</div>
```

Comment: addBox function adds the button to all <li> elements with the .container class. which means it'll add it to all of them.

Comment: instead of `$('.container li').append...` you need to get just the last item created

Answer (score 1):

Why do you copy the button everytime? He has an id, so you aren't allowed to copy him anyways.

The real problem as @tyler mackenzie correctly pointed out, is that your `'.container li'` selector will find all points not just the last one.

So here some code that solves those issues:

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  //When you click send it sends the item to the list
  $('#send').click(function() {
    var userMessage = $('.text-box').val();
    $('.text-box').val('');

    //If theres nothing in the text-box and send is clicked an alert pops up
    if (!userMessage) {
      alert("Please add some items to the list!")
    } else {
      //This appends the item typed into the text-box to the list
      var remBtn = $('<button class="removebox">');  // this creates a new button element
      remBtn.text('X');
      var li = $('<li>');
      li.text(userMessage);
      li.append(remBtn);
      $('.container').append(li);
    }
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="title" width="100%">
  <p> Shopping List</p>
</div>

<div class="container">
  <input class="text-box" placeholder="Please enter an item">
  <button id="send">submit</button>
</div>
```

Comment: Thanks for this as well. I'm going to study this and put it into practice.

Answer (score 0):

https://jsfiddle.net/62afjy7q/

Basically, I changed the way your button is hidden / shown (hide with css now), and i cloned it when appending to each one. I modified a bit of the html, putting the first group of content in its own div

```
<div class="container">
  <div class="input-container">
    <input class="text-box" placeholder="Please enter an item">
    <button id="send">submit</button>
    <button id="removebox">X</button>
  </div>

</div>

--- css ---
.input-container #removebox {
  display: none
}

--- js ---
function addBox(){
    $('.container li:last-child').append($('#removebox').clone());
     //$('#removebox').show();

};
```

Comment: Ahh I see what you did there. More efficient. Works perfectly. Thanks!!!

Comment: cloning an element with an id is dangerous. (messes up selectors and more) **ids have to be unique**

Comment: I like this answer because it's closer to the original, but it might be better to select the button using a name, or class instead of by id. as @SourceOverflow pointed out

Comment: if you use classes watch out to remove it in the new ones or you will (again) select multiple.

Comment: ah, yes, good point. I guess that doesn't really solve the problem.

Comment: my recommendation would to actually be to have the first instance have two classes -- removebox and template. You can hide the .template class in css, and when you clone it, clone '.removebox.template' and then removeClass('.template'), and then append it to the li.

Comment: @TKoL or you just create the elements dynamically in order to have clean code (espl. HTML)